# Login loop after activate proprietary controllers

Tags: nvidia

I have 16.04 (upgraded from 14.04) that worked well.

Once I activated Nvidia proprietary controller, I get locked in a login loop.

I tried `ctrl + alt + F1` to `F6`, none of them worked (got a black screen).

I made a bootable USB from where I have acces to original disk, from there I tried delting `/home/<user>/.Xauthority`but it didn't work.

What I would like is just to revert the activation of Nvidia proprietary controller, getting it back to `X.Org X Server`.

Before been considered a duplicated, I wen't carefully through [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics) but nothing there could be applied to my issue.

Comment: Have you disabled secure boot in the BIOS?

Comment: I didn't until you suggested, but nothing changed.

Comment: Now that you've disabled it, use recovery mode to purge and reinstall the Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to boot my system normally (but without nvidia drivers). I think all the credit should be given to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics), but it was hard to me to figure out how to do some things. I'll try to give some important details.
The steps I took are:

### Enter recovery mode or *'BOOT into GRUB'*

I only have Ubuntu on my install, so no GRUB menu appears on booting. Instead had to press **only once** `'esc'` key, right after the bios logo dissapeared (prior to 16.04 the key has to be left `'shift'`)

At the begining, as [AndroidDev](https://askubuntu.com/users/518562/android-dev) suggested I dissabled secure boot in the BIOS, but later I enabled it again and could enter in recovery mode without any problem, so I would say it has nothing to do.

Once I entered in the GRUB menu, was easy to boot in recovery mode, just have to look around until you see the option that explicits 'recovery mode' (I had several, I suposes each of them references one version of the kernel, so I booted with the highest (latest).

### Uninstall nvidia drivers

I then choose the root console and issued

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

but finally it didn't do anything, because filesystem was readonly.
So first I had to run fsck, from the previous menu (not from console).
After that, I rerun the purge command.

### Deleting `.Xauthority`

Somewhere in the process deleted /home//.Xauthority with `sudo rm /home/<user>/.Xauthority`

I'm sure only this didn't do the trick, but is something more to try.

## Installing the proprietary drivers

I tried once again to install the nvidia drivers, but this time from the terminal... as soon as drivers were installed and restarted, I got stucked in the same login loop ... so had to purge the drivers again.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be posted as an answer, since basically it is a reformulation of another answer. Please feel free to guide me with that.

Comment: Now I know I can't use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open a terminal, so have to check that, and I can't install Nvidia drivers, wich I think may be causing Android Emulator nor genymotion not working at all.